# how to add elements within a array structured object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have this structure of javascript object

```
var propertiesObject = {
 dataFormat: 'json', 
 dataSource: {
    build: {
        caption: "Some caption"

        }, categories: [
        {
        category:[
            {"label":"January"},
            {"ADD NEW HERE DYNAMICALLY"}
        ]
      }
    ],
    dataset: [
        {
            seriesname: "ISB",
            data: [
             {
                 "value": "10000",
                 {"ADD NEW HERE DYNAMICALLY"}
             }
            ]
        },
        {"ADD NEW HERE DYNAMICALLY"}
    ]
} }
```

and I want to add new element dynamically in  "category" and "dataset", then  after all dynamic data added I will stringify it to json.

my problem is how can I achieve this?

I'm really confused with the several solutions i found and it's not the outcome i need.

thank you for any help.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "add dynamically" here, there isn't enough context.  Is the "dynamic data" some sort of response data that just needs to be parsed into an existing data structure?  a new structure with the specified shape? Can you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score -1):

Use that child array as the way you use normal arrays.

```
// push directly to array
propertiesObject.category.push(new element);
```

About array push: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp